# How to download a file from sharepoint using client object model

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm new to sharepoint.

Could anyone share how to download a file from sharepoint?

I'm able to list the files in a folder but while try to download the files 
it is throwing **"403 - Forbidden"** exception.

By this line

```
FileInformation fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, pFile.ServerRelativeUrl);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom/17708174#17708174