# Save DataTable to Sharepoint Document Library as XML

Tags: c#, xml, sharepoint, datatable

As the title of the post describes, I am attempting save a DataTable straight into a SharePoint Document Library.

Here is what I had originally:

```
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                //add rows to datatable
                foreach(GridViewRow row in Gv.Rows)
                {
                    //omitted for the sake of brevity
                }


                dt.WriteXml("TEMP PATH", true);
```

However, instead of saving it to a temporary location as an xml file, can I do a sort of all in one where I convert the DataTable into an xml format and upload it to the Document Library? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the XML file to a temporary location and then save that file to sharepoint document library. AFter the file is uploaded successfully, you can delete the file.

For uploading file : [How to download/upload files from/to SharePoint 2013 using CSOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom)

[How do you upload a file to a document library in sharepoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Would you advise that I do the above by saving the XML file to a folder in the webpart solution? If so, could you provide me with an example?

Comment: I would advise you to save the XML file to sharepoint document library.

Comment: To clarify, I mean save the xml file to a folder in the project directory as the temporary location, then send that to the SP doc lib. So save xml to folder in project dir -> send xml to doc lib -> delete xml from folder in project dir. I am currently, having issue trying to find the correct path so I can save said xml to folder in my project.

Comment: Yes. This is what I am trying to say